# Use custom command to start SFTP server in pysftp/Paramiko

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, winscp, pysftp

In WinSCP is an option to edit the SFTP server command/path (in the protocol options):

[image: winscp image]

Is there also such an option in pysftp/Paramiko or in an another SFTP package for Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What that option in WinSCP does is that it runs SFTP over the "exec" channel, instead of the "sftp subsystem" channel. An (untested) equivalent in Python Paramiko:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

# authenticate here

chan = ssh.get_transport().open_session()
chan.exec_command("/path/to/sftp-server")
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient(chan)
```